# Обновление программы из лаунчера

Tags: c#, обновление

У меня есть лаунчер для игры (скачивает саму игру и запускает её с параметрами). Я хочу что-бы при обновлении лаунчер докачивал обновление, а не качал всю игру заново. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Качаете лаунчером обновление вместо всей игры, распаковываете его поверх прошлой версии, запускаете игру. В чем сложность?

Comment: Да, но как отделить отдельные файлы из билда?

Comment: То есть у вас вопрос не про сам лаунчер, а про то как создать обновление имея 2 папки (с базовой и с новой версией игры) ?

Comment: Скорее так будет более правильно)

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос тогда

Comment: когда выпускаем свежий билд, всем его файлам номер версии (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку:
Лаунчер просто сравнивает версии всех файлов(прямое соответствие имён) в локальной папке установленной игры и, например, в сетевой папке хранилища эталонных файлов -- если версия файла-эталона больше, лаунчер его копирует в папку игры с заменой устаревшего файла;
Новые файлы-эталоны, которым нет соответствия в папке установленной игры -- копируются безусловно;
Старые файлы, которым нет соответствия в хранилище эталонов -- удаляются.

используя, например [класс FileVersionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx) =)